# How to use the bootstrap corousel slide image in desktop view at the same time how to stop it in mobile view?

Tags: bootstrap-4

In my carousel slide there are 4 images slide. but I don't want the carousel in mobile view, I just want single image in mobile view.

css change

`.carousel-inner .item.active {visibility:hidden;}`

Comment: use Media Queries

Answer (score 1):

You can use [responsive option](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html) of OwlCarousel2

For example:

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            touchDrag: false, // turn off for mobile
            nav: false
        },
        // breakpoint from 480 up
        480:{
            touchDrag: true, // turn on for 480 up devices
            nav: true
        }
    }
})
```